# MySQL query - get latest score per user and category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So this is an image of my database structure:
[image: database]

Basically its a quiz app where every question and quiz has a category (since there is also the quiz category mixed - which includes questions from several categories). Every time the user plays a new quiz a new entry in the quiz table will be made - recording the user, the category, the score and the start and end time of the quiz.

I need a query in which i display the LATEST score per user and category.
(nice to have: also the average score per user and category)

It should look like [image: this] in the end. Obviously I have a query already but it doesn't really work well, since Max Mustermann only shows one result, but actually has results in 4 categories. I don't really know why all others users show the results they played, maybe that is because they only played one quiz per category. But Max Mustermann played the category "Mixed" once only and it is not displayed.

This is the code I am using currently:

```
$query_scores_per_cat_per_user = "
        SELECT category, t1.scores AS scores
        FROM categories 
        left JOIN quizzes as t1 ON categories.id=t1.FK_categories
        left JOIN quizzes AS t2
          ON t1.FK_users = t2.FK_users 
                AND t1.end_timestamp < t2.end_timestamp
        WHERE t2.FK_users IS NULL 
        and t1.fk_categories = ".$category_id." and t1.FK_users=".$all_users_id."
        order by category ASC"
```

Could you help me finding the mistake? I am really lost here.
Thank you!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the category in the second `join`.

```
$query_scores_per_cat_per_user = "
    SELECT category, t1.scores AS scores
    FROM categories 
    left JOIN quizzes as t1 ON categories.id=t1.FK_categories
    left JOIN quizzes AS t2
      ON t1.FK_users = t2.FK_users 
        AND t1.FK_categories = t2.FK_categories
        AND t1.end_timestamp < t2.end_timestamp
    WHERE t2.FK_users IS NULL 
    and t1.fk_categories = ".$category_id." and t1.FK_users=".$all_users_id."
    order by category ASC"
```

Comment: Do you know if it is also possible to display the number of quizzes played per user and category and the average score together with the higest score? - i have a query but it shows me weird results.

Comment: You need to join with subqueries that use `GROUP BY` to get those results.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t2.UserName, category, Sum(t1.scores) AS scores, AVG(t1.scores)
        FROM categories 
        left JOIN quizzes as t1 ON categories.id=t1.FK_categories
        left JOIN quizzes AS t2
          ON t1.FK_users = t2.FK_users 
                AND t1.end_timestamp < t2.end_timestamp
        WHERE t2.FK_users IS NULL 
        and t1.fk_categories = ".$category_id." and t1.FK_users=".$all_users_id."
Group by t2.UserName, Category,
        order by t1.Scores desc, category
```

I didnt try..